# Jquery stop queueing while animation is not finished on hover

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, queue, show

I checked out a few posts and tried to put either stop() or filter(':not(:animated)') to avoid queueing up animations on my hover but it doesn't work. The page won't load anymore everytime I try to add those function in my code.

```
<div id="competences">
    <div id="logoComp">
        <div>
            <img id="devLogo" src="img/logoDev.png" />
            <p>Developpement</p>
            <p>- HTML/CSS -</br>
            - Javascript -</br>
            - PHP -</br>
            - Java -</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img id="responsiveLogo" src="img/responsive.png" />
                <p>Responsive</p>
                <p>Ce site est responsive et la plupart de mes projets le sont également.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img id="logoPrint" src="img/logoPrint.png" />
                <p>Graphisme</p>
                <p>Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign, Blender, After Effects, Premiere</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

// when hover over the selected image change the opacity to 1  
    var n = $("#competences").length;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        $('#logoComp div').each(function(){
        $(this).hover(  
        function(){  
          $(this).find('img').hide("slow");
          $(this).find('p').delay(500).show("slow");

       },  
       function(){  
          $(this).find('p').hide("hide");
          $(this).find('img').delay(500).show("slow");
       }
       );  
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Why are your a) adding handlers in an `each` (jQuery does not require that) and b) doing it in a loop (adding the handlers more than once!)

Comment: Also ids are unique so you only ever iterate once regardless of how many are on the page???

Answer (score 0):

You need to simplify your code and stop using IDs as they must be unique on a page (jQuery will only "see" the first one if you have multiples). Use classes instead.

You also need to decide when to `stop()` existing animations or they will chain together. `stop()` flushes the animation queue for that element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // when hover over the selected image change the opacity to 1  
    $(".competences .logoComp div").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('img').stop().hide("slow");
        $(this).find('p').stop().delay(500).show("slow");

    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('p').stop()hide("hide");
        $(this).find('img').stop().delay(500).show("slow");
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zymje5Lq/1/

This is not perfect, but avoids some of the problems :)

Comment: Oh nvm didn't see you forgot a . after stop(). The problem now is my animation stop midway and my img instead of reappearing again just stay hidden.